# How to set size of html button

Tags: html, button, size

I have a button:

```
 <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" href="gmail.html">                
                    Poczta Gmail
                </a>
```

How to set it size to 1/3 of page width?
EDIT: Or just set it to 200px?

Comment: What is using the `data-role` attribute? Bootstrap?

Comment: `width:33%` should work if your page width is set to 100%.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? @HobbitHole: it would, if the `body` is the parent of the element, or the parent is, itself, equal to the width of the `body`.

Comment: @Jivings I was wondering too. Found [this](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Comment: HAve no idea it is for useless subject of not mine speciality just do it and forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the button to have 33% width. of course you need a more specific selector than a. This is just an example.

[**Little Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fT4SW/)

**HTML:**

```
<a data-role="button" data-inline="true" href="gmail.html">                
    Poczta Gmail
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT (as question changed):**

If you want it to be set to 200px width you can do the following:

```
a {
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Also the container would have to be 100% page width.

Comment: @RobertKilar CSS is what styles HTML elements. You can't modify the look of an element without it.

Comment: @RobertKilar - as in inline style? style="width:33%;display:inline-block;" as an attribute. However it is best practice to seperate your styling and mark up.

Comment: @Jivings +1 Thanks for pointing that out. That is of course a requirement.

Comment: That 200px is working thanks, but the text is on the top of the button, got to center it.

Comment: It alligns horizontally, looking for verticaly.